# Appointment scheduling system in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb, scheduling

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I'm making an appointment scheduling system using MariaDB and NodeJS, doctors can insert their time availabilities and users patients can request an appointment based on those availabilities and already scheduled appointments.

### Specifications

The shortest time unit is half an hour and appointments are of one hour.

So in example: in between 14:00 and 16:00 there can be 3 possible combinations for appointments (14:00-15:00; 14:30-15:30; 15:00-16:00).

**availability table**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| id | start               | end                 | repeate     | endRepetition | doctorId |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 1  | 2020-08-18 14:00:00 | 2020-08-18 15:00:00 | 604.800.000 | 2021-08-18    | 1        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 2  | 2020-08-25 15:00:00 | 2020-08-25 16:00:00 | 0           | null          | 1        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 3  | 2020-08-19 12:00:00 | 2020-08-19 14:00:00 | 0           | null          | 2        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

repeate is stored in ms

**Appointments table**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id | start               | end                 | description | doctorId | patientId |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 2020-08-18 14:00:00 | 2020-08-18 15:00:00 | checkup     | 1        | 1         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 2020-08-19 12:00:00 | 2020-08-19 13:00:00 | stuff       | 2        | 2         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

**What I'd expect to get**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| start               | end                 | doctorId |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2020-08-19 13:00:00 | 2020-08-19 14:00:00 | 2        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2020-08-25 14:00:00 | 2020-08-25 15:00:00 | 1        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2020-08-25 14:30:00 | 2020-08-25 15:30:00 | 1        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2020-08-25 15:00:00 | 2020-08-25 16:00:00 | 1        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

This is between 2020-08-18 and 2020-08-25 included

### What I tried to do

My main concerns are about scheduling an appointment starting on a time slot and ending in another one.
For example if a doctor inserts a recurrent availability  every Tuesday 14:00-15:00, but for Tuesday 2020-08-25 the user inserts also an availability for 15:00-16:00.
In this case, according to the specifics, there could be an event starting at 14:30 and ending at 15:30 with 14:00-15:00 and 15:00-16:00 being two different rows in availabilities table.

Actually for now my only idea is to divide all the availabilities in the shortest time slot (1/2 h), check if these are in between of appointments start and end date, and in this case exclude them.
Then combine the result together in all possible combinations of one hour slots.

Another thing that I tried was using some Gaps and Islands approach, first I materialized all the availabilities in a specific amount of time (lets say 1 day), then I joined all of them which were contiguous (i.e. same day 14:00-15:00 and 15:00-16:00), in the end I checked for availabilities with some empty space:

```
IF (((availability.start - appointment.start) <= 3600 && (availability.start - appointment.start) > 0) || ((availability.end - appointment.end) >= 3600 && availability.end - appointment.end) > 0))
```

But with this type of control I can only check if there is space in the start or in the end of an availability, not in between and especially not if there are multiple appointments in that availability.

Comment: Yes, in between 14:00 and 15:00 there can be three

Comment: My bad, it’s between 14 and 16 that there are 3  possible combinations. My point is if the user insert a recurrent availability for every monday from 14:00 to 15:00, and for a specific monday inserts aldo an availability for 15-16, how do I schedule an appointment in between those two availabilities?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your feedback, I tried to clear it up

Comment: Much better,  but, as previously mentioned, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query